Background worker doesn't work on real devices
The application requires periodic (15-30 mins) data synchronization with the backend.
I implemented this using the WorkManager API, but I encountered the issue that synchronization only triggers when the application is running; if the user or the Android OS terminates the application, my sync worker stops working.
At the same time, I see that synchronization works on the emulator even if I terminate the process.
I have read a lot of information on this topic but cannot see any mistake on my end.
Could you please advise what might be the problem?
My test worker (writes logs in file):
class TestWorker
    (appContext: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

        Timber.d("Message from worker")
        return Result.success()
    }
}

My Application (starts sync worker):
@HiltAndroidApp
@Singleton
class WorkTestApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val fileLogger = FileLogger(context = this)
        val reportingTree = ReportingTree(fileLogger)

        Timber.plant(reportingTree)

        val periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<TestWorker>(
            repeatInterval = 15,
            repeatIntervalTimeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES
        ).build()

        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this)
        workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            "SYNC_WORK_NAME",
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
            periodicWorkRequest
        )
    }
}

App manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:name=".WorkTestApp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WorkerTest"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.WorkerTest">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>


On some real devices some manufacturers put very crappy battery management apps that basically kill off any background processes. May be this behaviour is affecting your app. See https://dontkillmyapp.com/ may be you can instruct the user to whitelist your app if the manufacturer offers that feature.

Yes, I know about this problem. I tried to switch the background activity control to "No restrictions" mode. But this does not help either :(

I've had really devices where even though you have configured no restriction the software was so bad it ignored the configuration, the only solution was to force uninstall the crappy software.

The only other thing that might cause you a problem is using ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP can be a problem if for some reason you once created a Periodic work request on this devices with period of days for example, using KEEP means your change to 15 minutes might be ignored an it still left at a period of days. Best to use a policy of UPDATE or CANCEL_AND_REENQUEUE

@Andrew, thanks for the answer. This is useful information for me, although this is not my case, since when the application process is running, the worker is correctly triggered approximately every 15 minutes.
In any case, thanks!

On one device I managed to identify and exact the APK of their crappy battery management service, then decompile the code to find it only ever used a hard coded list of "WhatsApp" to not kill, ignoring any other configured list. Have you tried it on many other devices? Is the behaviour the same on all real devices?

I tried it on different devices, but unfortunately they were all from the same manufacturer: Xiaomi.
I still hoped that there was some problem in my code, and not a device limitation ((

I've built the code in the question (thought I removed the use of Timber and used a standard Log statement to simplify things, as well as using an UPDATE policy). And then tested it on a non Xiaomi device that I believe does not have any stupid battery management software installed by the manufacturer and it fires ever 15 minutes, when the app is in the background or even when the phone has gone to sleep. This again points to my first comment that it is a problem with the Xiaomi phone and not your code.

On some real devices some manufacturers put very crappy battery management apps that basically kill off any background processes. May be this behaviour is affecting your app.
See dontkillmyapp.com may be you can instruct the user to whitelist your app if the manufacturer offers that feature.
I've built the code in the question (thought I removed the use of Timber and used a standard Log statement to simplify things, as well as using an UPDATE policy). And then tested it on a non Xiaomi device that I believe does not have any stupid battery management software installed by the manufacturer
It fires ever 15 minutes, when the app is in the background or even when the phone has gone to sleep
This points that it is a problem with the Xiaomi phone and not your code.
Update
Just tested on a Samsung S7 and it works as expected in the background.
